# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory trying to open a file

Tags: python

I am very new to Python so please forgive the following basic code and problem, but I have been trying to figure out what is causing the error I am getting (I have even looked at similar threads on S.O.) but can't get past my issue.

Here is what I am trying to do:

- loop through a folder of CSV files
- search for a 'keyword' and delete all lines containing the 'keyword'
- save output to a separate folder

Here is my code:

```
import os, fnmatch
import shutil

src_dir = "C:/temp/CSV"
target_dir = "C:/temp/output2"
keyword = "KEYWORD"

for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
    os.path.join(src_dir, f)
    with open(f):
        for line in f:
            if keyword not in line:
                write(line)
                shutil.copy2(os.path.join(src_dir, f), target_dir)
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'POS_03217_20120309_153244.csv'
```

I have confirmed that the folder and file do exist. What is causing the `IOError` and how to I resolve it? Also, is there anything else wrong with my code that would prevent me from performing the entire task?

Comment: Fundamentally, the problem here was a typo: doing `os.path.join(src_dir, f)` **does not change the value of `f`**, so `open(f)` does not see the `src_dir` path.

Answer (score 20):

Hmm, there are a few things going wrong here.

```
for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
    os.path.join(src_dir, f)
```

You're not storing the result of `join`. This should be something like:

```
for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
    f = os.path.join(src_dir, f)
```

This open call is is the cause of your `IOError`. (Because without storing the result of the `join` above, `f` was still just 'file.csv', not 'src_dir/file.csv'.)

Also, the syntax:

```
with open(f):
```

is close, but the syntax isn't quite right. It should be `with open(file_name) as file_object:`. Then, you use to the `file_object` to perform read or write operations.

And finally:

```
write(line)
```

You told python *what* you wanted to write, but not *where* to write it. Write is a method on the file object. Try `file_object.write(line)`.

**Edit**: You're also clobbering your input file. You probably want to `open` the output file and write lines to it as you're reading them in from the input file.

See: [input / output in python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Thanks all for the great feedback! I'll look over the suggestions and see if I can get my code to work.

Answer (score 11):

Even though @Ignacio gave you a straightforward solution, I thought I might add an answer that gives you some more details about the issues with your code...

```
# You are not saving this result into a variable to reuse
os.path.join(src_dir, f)
# Should be
src_path = os.path.join(src_dir, f)

# you open the file but you dont again use a variable to reference
with open(f)
# should be
with open(src_path) as fh

# this is actually just looping over each character 
# in each result of your os.listdir
for line in f
# you should loop over lines in the open file handle
for line in fh

# write? Is this a method you wrote because its not a python builtin function
write(line)
# write to the file
fh.write(line)
```

Answer (score 5):

Um...

```
with open(os.path.join(src_dir, f)) as fin:
    for line in fin:
```

Also, you never output to a new file.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem like so:

```
src_dir = "C:\\temp\\CSV\\"
target_dir = "C:\\temp\\output2\\"
keyword = "KEYWORD"

for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
    file_name = os.path.join(src_dir, f)
    out_file = os.path.join(target_dir, f)
    with open(file_name, "r+") as fi, open(out_file, "w") as fo:
        for line in fi:
            if keyword not in line:
                fo.write(line)
```

Comment: You do not need the `+` in the line ``open(file_name, "r+")``. According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files): "`'r+'` opens the file for both reading and writing." In this case, you only want to read from `file_name`. Additionally, I suggest (although this is mostly preference) you combine your last three lines to ``fo.write('\n'.join(line for line in fi if keyword not in line))``. Doing this reduces the number of calls to `f.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and fixed by appending the directory path in the loop. script not in the same directory as the files. dr1 ="~/test" directory variable

```
 fileop=open(dr1+"/"+fil,"r")
```