# IOError: [Errno 2] when I want to create a file

Tags: python, django, join, path

I'm working on my django app, and I have problem with one line of my code:

```
open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'templates', 'generated', 'calendar', month.strftime('%Y-%m.html')), 'w').write(html)
```

Should works fine, because when I printed this line of code I got full path to file.

No I got an error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: IOError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765227/python-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Is  `settings.BASE_DIR` a relative path?

Comment: What is the file path given in the error and how does your file system look - do all of the directories in the path exist?